# Manage Sqlite connections in java for performance in a single threaded environment

Tags: java, sqlite

What is the best (highest performance) way in java to manage reading/writing to an SqlLite file?

**1. Create one connection object**

Create and share a single `Connection` object on app startup. In this case do the calls need to be synchronised/serialised? Java programmers seem to like always closing connections to prevent bad code leaving a a connection in a bad state or with unclosed statements, etc...

**2. Open and close a connection for every transaction**

Avoids the above mentioned problem, and would allow for the code to be run in a multi threaded environment if need be in the future? I also read that some mobile versions of java may require this behaviour.

I am hoping someone else already has experience in this area and can share it, otherwise I am going to have to learn the hard way. I am using the [xerial jdbc](https://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) driver if that makes a difference

Comment: Are you working on Android?

Comment: @JermaineXu If he were, he would not need xerial jdbc ...

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports three different threading modes:

- **Single-thread**. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is
  unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
- **Multi-thread**. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
  threads provided that no single database connection is used
  simultaneously in two or more threads.
- **Serialized**. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
  threads with no restriction.

For details see http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Note one multi-thread problem I've encountered is if you close a connection in one thread while still reading from a ResultSet in another thread. If you use the native library this will cause a fatal access violation error and crash the JVM proces. You would need to detect this condition in your code and not read from the ResultSet or even close the ResultSet.